# como plotar sombra no eixo x com ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um data.frame que possui esse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico com uma área sombreada no eixo x. Entretanto, quando adiciono `geom_rect()` com as informações da área sombreada, recebo o erro

```
"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'value' não encontrado"
```

Meu código:

```
library(ggplot2)

rect1 <- data.frame(xmin = as.Date('1965-01-01'), 
                    xmax = as.Date('1982-12-01'), 
                    ymin = -Inf, 
                    ymax = Inf)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(data = rect1,
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.4)
```

OBS: o código não dá erro antes do geom_rect, somente após inseri-lo.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Olá Marcos, bem vindo ao SOpt. Editei sua pergunta para ajudar a melhorar a apresentação, mas ainda deve incluir ou seus dados. Como apontado no comentário de Marcus Nunes, quem for tentar responder sua questão deve ser capaz de copiar e colar o código postado em seus computadores, rodá-lo, e chegar no mesmo erro (i.e., um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou as variáveis `date` e `value` na estética global, o que faz com que sejam indicadas para todas geometrias, incluindo a `geom_rect`, que não a encontra em `rect1`.

Indique `x` e `y` na estética da `geom_line` para ficarem restritos a ela, ou use a opção `inherit.aes = FALSE` na `geom_rect`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("1965-01-01"), as.Date("1973-02-01"), by = "month"),
  value = as.vector(LakeHuron))

rect <- data.frame(
  xmin = as.Date("1969-01-01"),
  xmax = as.Date("1971-12-31"),
  ymin = -Inf,
  ymax = Inf)

ggplot(dados) +
  geom_line(aes(date, value)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            rect, alpha = .4)
# OU
ggplot(dados, aes(date, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            rect, alpha = .4, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]